# Logistic regression: Significant difference inbetween marginal effects

Tags: regression, logistic, logit, marginal-distribution, effects

I was wondering how I could check if the calculated marginal effects within a logistic regression are significantly different from each other. Is it sufficient to check if the corresponding Beta-coefficients are different from each other? The idea is to rank the effects corresponding to their effect size.

My underlying assumption is that I cannot use the logistic regression Beta-coefficients in order to rank my variables. Is this correct? As far as I know they only indicate the direction of the effect.

Thank you very much for clarification.

(I use Stata, the marginal effect command used is “mchange”)